# How to find word in text?

Tags: python

I have to find if word is present in text.I have to do `FPS` present in `PS 18 26888 12345`. In this it should detect PS though `'F'` is not present in `'PS 18 26888 12345'`. I have tried

```
if "FPS" in "PS 18 26888 12345":
    --executing following code
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand -- why should a test if `FPS` is in a string return `True` when `FPS` is *not* in the string?

Comment: Are you looking for ´F´ or ´P´ or ´S´ in text?

Answer (score 2):

```
if "FPS" in "PS 18 26888 12345":
```

This looks for the substring `"FPS"` in full (so `'ab' in 'abba'` is `True` but `'abc' in 'abba'` is `False`), but I think you want to find if any of `"F"` or `"P"` or `"S"` are in the string. In which case you should use:

```
if any(char in "PS 18 26888 12345" for char in "FPS"):
```

Comment: That is a reasonable guess (so I won't downvote it) but an obscure question should be closed if not clarified rather than answered based on a guess of their meaning.

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm like 99% sure that's what OP means from their question "In this it should detect PS". I agree, we shouldn't guess but I think we can allow a reasonable amount of leeway for non-native english speakers who have trouble conveying what they want.

Comment: As I said, it is a reasonable guess, but my certainty is considerably less than 99% -- perhaps they want to know if a *substring* of `FPS` is in it so that `PS` is okay but `SP` isn't.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: From google vision api im getting text from image and from that text im detecting license no. Now i have to take location from text. Using regex im geeting License Id as PS 18 16373 73773 and actual text is FPS 18 16373 73773. So to add location in json file with license id. So to compare text with value so i need that logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = "FPS"
S = 'PS 18 26888 12345'

def checkValue(A, S):
    has_value = False
    while A:
        if A in S:
            has_value = True
            break
        else:
            A = A[1:]
    return has_value

if checkValue(A, S):
    print "Ok!!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all that are contained in your text:

```
from itertools import  combinations,chain

text =  "PS 18 26888 12345"
sear = "FPS"

comb = chain.from_iterable( combinations(sear, r = length) 
                            for length in range(1,len(sear)+1))

for f in comb:
    lu = ''.join(f)
    if ''.join(lu) in text:
        print(text, " contains ", lu)
```

Output:

```
PS 18 26888 12345  contains  P
PS 18 26888 12345  contains  S
PS 18 26888 12345  contains  PS
```

This

```
comb = chain.from_iterable( combinations(sear, r = length) 
                            for length in range(1,len(sear)+1))
```

creates all combinations from `sear` of length `[1, 2, 3, ..., len(sear)]`. 
For `FPS` this is

```
('F',) ('P',) ('S',) ('F', 'P') ('F', 'S') ('P', 'S') ('F', 'P', 'S')
```

which are joined back to a string with ''.join(..) and each checked against your big string.

Doku:

[itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable)
[itertools.combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

The "mechanism" is documented in [power-recipies](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) on the itertools-page as `powerset`:

```
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

which I modified to not contain the empty tuple

`comb` itself is an iterables so you can "use" it only once, persist it into a list if you need it more then once:

```
combList = list(comb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach if you want:

```
data_1='PS 18 26888 12345'
data_2='FPS'


print(list(map(lambda x:" ".join(list(filter(lambda y:x in data_1,x))),data_2)))
```

output:

```
['', 'P', 'S']
```